# Optimize four nested for loops

Tags: r, for-loop, nested

I have four nested for loops. How can I optimize this ? I implement the following code but it takes too long.

```
p1=0.1
q1=0.3
p2=0.2
q2=0.4
n=10
r1=2
bincoeff=function(k,S1, R2, S2) {
 return ( factorial(k+S1+R2+S2)/(factorial(k)*factorial(S1)*factorial(R2)*factorial(S2)) )
}
out=0
applyFormula= function(n, r1, p1, q1, p2, q2){
 if (r1 < 0) {out <- 0} 
else{
for (k in 0:r1) {
  nmk= n-k
   for (S1 in 0:nmk) {
     for (R2 in 0:nmk) {
       for (S2 in 0:nmk) {
         if ( S1+R2+S2 == nmk ) {
          out = out+ (bincoeff(k,S1,R2,S2)*(p1^k)*(q1^S1)*(p2^R2)*(q2^S2))
         }
       }
     }
   }
  }
   return (out)
  }
 }
```

I have after to apply this function to each row of my big data so it takes several minutes...
All the help you can offer me is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: FYI: The `purr` package has tons of great tools for situations like this.

Comment: the bincoef function is vectorised so you can pass it vector, rather than calculating it one at a time. This (I think) you can use for the k loop: `for (k in 0:r1) { ;
  nmk= n-k ;
  e = expand.grid(S1=0:nmk, R2=0:nmk, S2=0:nmk) ;
  e <- e[rowSums(e) == nmk, ] ;
  out <- out + sum(bincoeff(k,e$S1,e$R2,e$S2)*(p1^k)*(q1^e$S1)*(p2^e$R2)*(q2^e$S2)) ;
}`